# Guessing Game - random # 1 thru 100, asks the user 5 times to guess correct number.....BEGINNER JAVA

Tags: java

Design an application that picks a random number 1 through 100, and then prompt the user to guess the number, warning the user they only have 5 tries remaining to guess correctly.  After each guess, report to the user whether he or she is correct or guess was too high or too low.  If guesses correctly, print out congratulatory message.  If guess 5 times unsuccessfully, print a message saying the game is over.  At the end of the game, prompt hte user to indicate whether or not he/she wishes to play again.

I specifically need help with the ending, and I guess also the layout of the code... I run it and it continually runs, I've tried using several websites and my textbook but no luck, thank you in advance!!

Java, Net beans 8.2

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame 
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        int answer, guess,attemptsNum = 0;
        final int maxAttempts = 5;
        String str, another = "y";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();
        answer = generator.nextInt(101)+1;

        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
        System.out.println("Enter your guess (0 to quit):");

        {
            guess = scan.nextInt();
            while (guess != 0)
            {
                if(guess==answer)
                        System.out.println("Right!");
                else if (guess<answer)
                    System.out.println("Your guess was too LOW.");
                else if (guess>answer)
                    System.out.println("Your guess was too HIGH.");
            }

            System.out.println("Want to Play again?(y/n)");
            another = scan.next();

            while (guess != answer && ++attemptsNum < maxAttempts)
                if (attemptsNum == maxAttempts)
                    System.out.println ("The number was " + answer);
    }
}
```

}

Enter your guess (0 to quit): 20
Your guess was too LOW

Enter your guess (0 to quit): 35
Your guess was too LOW

Enter your guess (0 to quit): 80
Your guess was too HIGH

Enter your guess (0 to quit): 74
Your guess was too HIGH

Enter your guess (0 to quit): 56
Right! Guesses:5

Play again (y/n)?

Comment: What is the point of reading a string into the "another" variable?  You don't ever check the value.

Comment: Please add brackets to your loop statements to make them more readable. Also, if you enter any number other than 0, guess != 0 will always evaluate as true and result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of comments:

1. You need to work on your formatting of the code. This makes it a lot more readable.
2. Your generator generates a value between 1 and 101. It should just be `answer = generator.nextInt(100)+1;`
3. Your loops and some of your logic is wrong
4. I would suggest always creating a separate method outside `public static void main`. This is common practice, and this also allows you to call the method it self again.

This is how i would solve it:

```
import java.util.Random; import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main (String[]args) {
    runGame();
  }

  public static void runGame() {
    String another = "";
    int answer, guess,attemptsNum = 0;
    final int maxAttempts = 5;

    Random generator = new Random();
    answer = generator.nextInt(100)+1;

    System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
    System.out.println("Enter your guess (0 to quit):");

    guess = scan.nextInt();
    while (guess != answer && attemptsNum < maxAttempts-1 && guess != 0 ) {
      if(guess==answer)
            System.out.println("Right!");
      else if (guess<answer) {
        System.out.println("Your guess was too LOW.");
        attemptsNum++;
        guess = scan.nextInt();
      } 
      else {
        System.out.println("Your guess was too HIGH.");
        attemptsNum++;
        guess = scan.nextInt();
      }
    }

    System.out.println ("The number was " + answer);
    System.out.println("Want to Play again?(y/n)");
    another = scan.next();
    System.out.println("another = " + another);
    if(another.equals("y")) {
      runGame();
    } else {
      System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
  }
}
```

But either way, just continue to practice. You will get the hang of it!

Answer (score 1):

I see the outer while loop needs to be restructured and some of the logic is misplaced. Try the revised version, hope this helps. Comment me if you have any questions.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int answer, guess, attemptsNum = 0;
        final int maxAttempts = 5;
        String str, another = "y";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();
        answer = generator.nextInt(101) + 1;

        while (another.equals("y") || another.equals("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100");

            System.out.println("Enter your guess (0 to quit):");

            guess = scan.nextInt();
            attemptsNum = 0;
            while (guess != 0)

            {
                attemptsNum++;
                if (guess == answer) {
                    System.out.println("Right!");
                    break;
                } else if (guess < answer)
                    System.out.println("Your guess was too LOW.");
                else if (guess > answer)
                    System.out.println("Your guess was too HIGH.");

                if (attemptsNum == maxAttempts) {
                    System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
                    break;

                }

                System.out.println("Enter your guess (0 to quit):");
                guess = scan.nextInt();
            }

            System.out.println("Want to Play again?(y/n)");
            another = scan.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that javapedia.net has answered first, but I have come up with this answer independently. I have added brackets for readability. attemptsNum++ is added to the if statements for a guess being too high or low.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int answer, guess, attemptsNum = 0;
        final int maxAttempts = 5;
        String str, another = "y";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();
        answer = generator.nextInt(101) + 1;

        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100");
        System.out.println("Enter your guess (0 to quit):");

        guess = scan.nextInt();
        while (guess != 0) {
            if (guess == answer) {
                System.out.println("Right!");
                guess = 0;
            } else if (guess < answer) {
                System.out.println("Your guess was too LOW.");
                attemptsNum++;
                guess = scan.nextInt();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Your guess was too HIGH.");
                attemptsNum++;
                guess = scan.nextInt();
            }
            if (attemptsNum >= (maxAttempts-1)) {
                System.out.println("The number was " + answer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```